# Apps script Deployment Number Changing with every deployment

Tags: google-apps-script

Until today whenever I redeployed an Apps Script as a web app as far as I remember the deployment number was the same, but today I was pulling my hair out because my changes were not being reflected in the new deployment. Then I noticed that every time I deployed the script the URL was changing.

Is it me or has something changed?

Comment: Are you using the new editor?[reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments)

Comment: Hi cooper. Yes.

Comment: Did the reference help?  I presume your asking how do you edit a versioned deployment?